# Configuring celery with a .conf file

Tags: python, yaml, config, celery, loader

Good day.

I set up a separate project from the main one called myproject-celery. It is a buildout based project which contains the async part of my project. For convenience I want to have a file, that will be containing this machine's configuration. I know that celery provides the python config file, but I *do not* like this configuration style.

Let's say I have a configuration in a Yaml config file named **myproject.yaml**

What I want to achieve:

```
./bin/celery worker --config /absolute/path/to/project/myproject.yaml --app myproject.celery
```

The problem really is that I want to specify the file's location, because it can change. I tried writing a custom loader class, but I failed, cause I do not even know why and when the many custom methods of this class are called (the only doc that I found is http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.loaders.base.html?highlight=loader#id1 and It's no help for me). I tried to do something on import phase for the app module, but I can not pass the filepath to that module's code... The only solution that I came up with was using a custom ENV param that will contain the path, but I do not see why can't it be a launch param like in most apps, that I use(refering to pyramid with it's paster serve myproject.ini)

So the question: 
*What do I have to do to set up the config from a file that I could specify by an absolute path?*

EDIT:
The question was not answered, sow I posted an issue on celery's github. Will wait for a response.
https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/1100

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [`celery.loaders.base`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/df875598555847c7cbd18be26f70568bb8f1ab94/celery/loaders/base.py#L241) it looks like the method you want to override is [`read_configuration`](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/df875598555847c7cbd18be26f70568bb8f1ab94/celery/loaders/base.py#L241):

```
from celery.datastructures import DictAttr
from celery.loaders.base import BaseLoader


class YAMLLoader(BaseLoader):
    def read_configuration():
        # Load YAML file here and return a DictAttr instance
```

Comment: I thought about it, but I really want to provide an **absolute** location of the file. I really feel that doing a relative to the project config search would be bad.

Comment: @TarasVoynarovsky - there is no reason it has to be a relative config search - you can pull from `sys.argv` to get the path to your config file :-)

Comment: as I remember the celery configuration system does not allow me to add custom argument. It says that the option is not supported. Hmm. Well I could use direct access to sys.argv and look for the --config parameter, but that's kinda wrong when you access the params that are already parsed by celery directly through sys.argv